# put additional function to jqlite/jquery .val(parameter)

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jqlite

I am using a plugin that automatically alters some input/textarea/select elements value. I want to detect if that plugin used .val(parameter) on my input/textarea/select elements, because .val() doesn't trigger .change() event. I wan't it to do something like this

```
when (someelement).val(parameter) is used
then (someelement).trigger('change')
```

Note: it is the plugin that uses .val(parameter) and not me. So there is no way for me to manually hardcode .trigger('change') when some function from the plugin uses .val(parameter)

Comment: _"So there is no way for me to manually hardcode .trigger('change')"_ Have you tried adjusting `js` of plugin?

Comment: What is the plugin? Does it have an events api?